# Finding dimensions of functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, education

Hey guys I need help showing if a function is a vector space or not. I believe we show is addition and multipication holds. but I don't know. Also how do I find out dimensions of such functions.

The question

Show that the function $a_1 + a_2\sin x + a_3\cos x$ form a vector space. If it is what are the dimensions for it like how did you figure it out. Because I think it would be 3 because we are looking at $\{1, \sin x, \cos x\}$. But I don't know if it is right.

Also what about $b_1 + b_2\sin^2 x + b_3\cos^2 x$

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking at the **set** $S$ of functions of the shape $a+b\sin x+c\cos x$, where the numbers $a, b, c$ range over the reals.

We need to show that the **sum** of any two functions in $S$ is also in $S$, and that if $f$ is in $S$, so is $k$, for any real number $k$.  Both these things are straightforward to verify.

We also in principle need to verify some more basic things, for example that the $0$-function is in $S$, and that if $f$ is in $S$ so is $-f$. Also, we need (in principle) to verify the other vector space properties.

As to the dimension of this vector space, you are right, it is $3$, and the set $\{1,\sin x,\cos x\}$ is a basis. Certainly all the elements of our space are, by definition, linear combinations of $1,\sin x,\cos x$.

We need to show also that our three functions are *linearly independent*. So we need to check that if $a+b\sin x+c\cos x=0$ (identically) then all of $a,b,c$ are $0$.

If $a+b\sin x+c\cos x$ is identically $0$, then its  derivative $b\cos x-c\sin x$ is identically $0$. Put $x=0$. We conclude $b=0$. Put $x=\pi/2$. We conclude $c=0$. And finally since $a+b\sin x+c\cos x=0$, we get $a=0$. This completes the proof that $1,\sin x,\cos x$ are a linearly independent set.

---

We turn now to the set of all functions of the form $a+b\sin^2 x+c\cos^2 x$. These form a vector space, basically for the same reason as in our previous calculation. But $1,\sin^2 x,\cos^2 x$ are not linearly independent, since $1-\sin^2 x-\cos^2 x=0$.

You can verify without much trouble that $\{1,\sin^2 x\}$ is a basis of our vector space. Indeed any two of $1,\sin^2 x,\cos^2 x$ form a basis for the space.

Comment: Hi thank you for this but I need some clarification if you dont mind

Comment: So to show it is a vector space we are just showing that (a + bsinx + c cosx) + (d + esinx + fcosx) = (a+d) + (b+e)sinx + (c+f)cosx and that is the same as our function. And i do the same for multipication?

Comment: Sure. Maybe your questions can be cleared up in comments. Maybe I will need to add detail somewhere. Just no Chat.

Comment: And for number 2 why did you do (1 - sin^2x - cos^2x) i know it is 0 but why did you pick (1,-1,-1) as constants ? And why did the dimension go down to 2

Comment: and lastly online it says for it to be a vector space 10 conditions must suffice. DO we have to do that?

Comment: That's one thing we must show. But don't say that's the same as our function. We are dealing with a set of functions, not a single function. Take two functions in our set, say $p+q\sin x+r\cos x$ and $s+t\sin x+u\cos x$. then their sum is $(p+s) +(q+t)\sin x+(r+u)\cos x$, so is in our set.

Comment: our TA said we just have to show if the linear combinations are preserved. What does that mean

Comment: I knew, as you do, of the fact that $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$. So I knew that for example $\cos^2 x$ can be expressed as a simple linear combination of $1$ and $\sin^2 x$. That means the functions are not linearly independent.

Comment: hence making dim = 2

Comment: okay that cleared it up. THanks a lot

Comment: That means in effect that you need to show that if $f$ and $g$ are in the set, so is $af+bg$ for any constants $a$ and $b$. To do that, it is enough to show that if $f$ and $g$ are in the set, so are $kf$ for any $k$, and $f+g$. These are the first things mentioned in the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Soon this will seem easy to you.